# How do you move a mesh to the origin?

Tags: modeling

So I can import a 3D object, see screenshot.  That tiny orange (selected) object way below the workspace grid is my file.
[image]

How do I transform (I mean move, but Blender lingo for this seems to be "Transform") the object to the origin of the workspace and transform it's orientation so the long axis of the part is parallel to the Z axis?

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: In Blender "move" is called "move", as you'd expect (formerly "grab", hence the shortcut G). "Transform" is a convenient umbrella term for all of: Move, Scale, Rotate, which are "similarity transformations" in mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

To move it's location:
Select the object, move the 3D Cursor to the center (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>) or to a desired location, then move the selection to the cursor (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>).

To change the origin:
Select a part of the object in *Edit Mode*, move the 3D cursor to it, and then
switch to edit mode and snap the object to the cursor(<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>).

Rotate the object first if you want to change the angle.

Comment: Thank you Duarte, do you know if there are tutorials focused on learning 3D design or mechanical object construction?  I have been going through Blender fundamental tutorials, the learning curve is steep.  Also, what do you mean in your second paragraph when you discuss changing the origin?

Comment: In the second paragraph I meant the 3D cursor can be moved or snapped to a object, side or face, then use it to snap selected objects to it or even the the objects orientation point it's self.

Comment: Type in mechanical parts in utube for the rest